# ¿Cómo hacer que un div ocupe todo el espacio disponible en cada tipo de pantalla?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy creando una aplicación móvil con HTML y CSS en Bootstrap Studio, y tengo un div con un color de fondo que es el que contiene a los demás elementos de cada interfaz. El div cubre toda la pantalla en algunos smartphones, pero en los que tienen la pantalla más alargada se corta y no llega hasta el final de la pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo el div de la interfaz:

```
    .fondo-blanco {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 40px;
     background-color: #EBE9FB;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     max-height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     min-width: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
   }
```

Tengo además otro div parecido en donde me ocurre el mismo error:

```
.fondo-añadir {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #e088d7, #c185cf, #a480c3, #8a7ab3, #7473a1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar, las clases del grid de Bootstrap que estás utilizando para el div? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/